# Distribute Each Shifts Equally amongst Similarly Skilled Employees Using Optaplanner in Employee Roster

Tags: optaplanner

```
rule "Fairness: all similar skilled employees should work about the type of shifts"
when
    $f : Employee(skill=="SR")
    $s : Shift(shiftType=="NSR")
    accumulate(
        $a : ShiftAssignment(employee == $f, shiftType == $s);
        $total :count($a)
    )
then
    // Fairness and load balancing trick (see docs): squared to assure correctness in corner cases
    // Negative to balance it across employees
    scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, - ($total.intValue() * $total.intValue()));
```

end

I have written the above logical Constraint . Could someone guide me the right direction or point out the error in this logic

Comment: Please state your problem in the form of a question. What are you struggling with?

Comment: I have 3 skills (JR/SR/MO) and 3 Shifts wherein shifts have to been done by specific skilled group by adjusting weight in the AlternativeSkillCategory and have managed to assign Equal Shift assignments by adjusting the max and min assignments. However the distribution of Shift Types amongst those Assignments is uneven ie. assignment of Shifts Types within same group of Skilled Worker is unfair but the total number of assignment is fair. the drool rule i have made doesn't seem to make any difference. Could you please take a look on the drool rule ? –